# C - realloc causes an issue with structure

Tags: c, struct

First of all, my appology that the code I post below is a bit ambiguous, since I have to simplify it in a way that readers can understand (the original code is quite complicated).

In the code below:

1. There is a list of 10 items.
2. Each item has a list of info about it.
3. Each info has a list of name.

So I'm trying to populate the list of items, but I failed at reallocate the memory on line that I marked "`<<<<`". There is no compiling error, but when I print all the items's names out, it doesn't print any of those. I did some debugging on it and I'm pretty sure that the line "`<<<<`" causes an error, but I don't know why.

```
typedef struct {
    char *name;
} NAME;

typedef struct {
    int id;
    int nNames;
    NAME *names;
} INFO;

typedef struct {
    INFO *info;
} ITEM;

void *buildListInfo(LIST *list) {
    if (list != NULL) {
        list->nNames++;
        list->names = realloc(list->names, sizeof(INFO) * list->nNames++);  // <<<<
        list->names[list->nNames-1].name = "example"; // index 0 first
    }
    return list;
}

int main() {
    int itemSize = 10;
    ITEM *items = malloc(sizeof(ITEM)*itemSize);

    for (int i = 0; i < ind->nTerms; i++) {
        items[i].info = malloc(sizeof(INFO));
    }

    /* construct an array that holds the number of lists that an item has */
    int num[itemSize];
    for (int i = 0; i < itemSize; i++) {
        num[i] = 0;
    }

    /* build all items, each item has a list that contains its info (many) */
    while (<some_finite_condition>)
        for (int i = 0; i < itemSize; i++) {
            items[i].info[num[i]] = *buildList(&(items[i].info[list[i]]));
            num[i]++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`realloc()` takes two arguments -- the pointer to reallocate, and a new size. You're calling it with one argument, and that's some pretty major undefined behavior. Use function prototypes -- i.e., include `stdlib.h`!

Comment: That's a typo, in my actual code I have it the first argument, and stdlib.h is so included :) The problem is still there.

Comment: Well, I tried to take a closer look, and it seems like there must be *many* typos. The function you show isn't called anywhere; a function by a similar name *is* called, though, so perhaps that's it. With all the "typos", I can't tell for sure, but it seems *very* likely that the problem is you're passing a first argument to `realloc()` which is neither a pointer originally obtained from `malloc()` or `NULL`. If you pass garbage to `realloc()`, terrible things happen!

Answer (score 1):

You know that `realloc()` takes two arguments, right? The prototype is

```
void *realloc(void *ptr, size_t size);
```

E.g.,

```
 newsize = size + 50;
 if ((newp = realloc(p, newsize)) == NULL) {
      free(p);
      p = NULL;
      size = 0;
      return (NULL);
 }
 p = newp;
 size = newsize;
```

(From the OpenBSD [realloc(3) manual](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=realloc).)

Answer (score 0):

- Allocate for elements of size `NAME`, not `INFO`
- You increase `nNames` twice; and when you do `list->names[list->nNames-1]`, you are doing a buffer overflow.

Try changing this lines:

```
    list->names = realloc(list->names, sizeof(INFO) * list->nNames++);
```

by

```
    list->names = realloc(list->names, sizeof(NAME) * list->nNames);
```